# need to refresh the page content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter frame work and currently working on social networking kind of stuff. My problem is, i need to  notify the user of their friends activity with out reloading the page when the user clicks on the feeds link. 
I have tried the following script,

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
$('#reload').fadeOut("slow").load('user_feeds').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);
</script>
```

It increases the load to my server. any other idea for accomplishing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hitting the target....! I need to do it like face book wall.

Comment: What's the question here? How to reduce load? Obviously, reloading something from the server from every client every few seconds increases load! To tackle this problem you'd have to change the logic on server side - send a timestamp to see if something changed, use caching, ...

Comment: Use normal AJAX to check for new items. If there are, put them in there, if not, do nothing. That will reduce the load alot since you don't need to load the whole feed again.

Comment: You need to find techniques to reduce the server load. To reduce the http request then you can go for the Comet technique or ape-project for real time notifications. Another is that to reduce server side load (caused by server side programming language php, asp or jsp), then you can go for tools such as memcache or redis.

Answer (score 0):

Then try to decrease the time interval

```
<script>
 setInterval(function() {
 $('#reload').fadeOut("slow").load('user_feeds').fadeIn("slow");
 }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: The page need to be very dynamic,it should intimate the user as soon as there is an friends activity.

Answer (score 0):

Manoj what you are trying to achieve here is notifications and the data source residing on the server, so there is no way you can do that from the browser either by a pull or push from the server.

pull you can achieve by constant polling / frequent polling - usually by setting a timeout and getting the notifications.

push - ideally not really push you can achieve this by combining AJAX+Comet, this can also be achieved by long polling too where you maintain a constant connection with the server for any new updates and return data to server when there is an update.

let me know if this helps or you need more information

Comment: well please go through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) for comet programming and frequent polling is about doing an interval based polling to see if there is any data to be recieved by the client. both has their own advantages and disadvantages

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very interesting problem, what you need is an implementation of [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#Ajax_with_long_polling) .There is an event routing bus using comet called COMETD. COMETD also has javascript implementation and has bindings for Jquery. http://cometd.org/documentation/2.x/cometd-javascript